# How to return loop the button 5 times and then return in next row?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I create a `<CardItem />` from `native-base` and style a `<Button />`. I return the  from `releasedTime.map()` function.

If my `releasedTime` length < 6. The efficient is what i want.

Here is when `releasedTIme` length = 5
[image]

Here is when `eleasedTIme` length = 2
[image]
If `releasedTime` is a huge array, it becomes terrible like this
[image]
So i want it when map function loop 5 times ,it can be returned in next row.

I have no idea how to do it. I think a `{}` just can return once.

If write multiple  `{}` how do i know `releasedTime` loop how many times and use then with multiple `{}` ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my file use `<CardItem />`

```
<CardItem>
       <Body>             
         <Image source={{uri: photoHref }} style={{height: 200, width: '100%', resizeMode: 'stretch', flex: 1}}/>               
         <Body style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'flex-start', paddingTop: 5, flexWrap: 'wrap', width: '100%' }}>
            {releasedTime.map(value => {                      
              return (
                <Button key={value}>{`${hour}:${minute}`}</Button>
              );
            })}
         </Body>
       </Body>
</CardItem>
```

My `<Button />` from:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
  const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = {
  textStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    color: '#007aff',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#007aff',
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5
  }
};

export { Button };
```

I try caculate the index, it is still no wroking :(

```
<CardItem>
              <Body>             
                <Image source={{uri: photoHref }} style={{height: 200, width: '100%', resizeMode: 'stretch', flex: 1}}/>               
                  <Body style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start',flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 5, flexWrap: 'wrap', width: '100%' }}>
                    {releasedTime.map((value, index) => {
                        if( index / 5 <= 1) {
                          return (
                            <Button key={index}>{`${hour}:${minute}`}</Button>
                          );
                        } else {
                          return (
                            <Body style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start',flexDirection: 'row', paddingTop: 5, flexWrap: 'wrap', width: '100%' }}>
                              <Button key={index}>{`${hour}:${minute}`}</Button>
                            </Body>
                          );
                        }

                    })}
                  </Body>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
```

Comment: use react-native Flatlist's numcolumns numcolumns props. See this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns

Comment: Looks like it can be used. I will try it . Thanks for sharing @akhilxavier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of the map function to determine, if there are 5 or more elements inside the array and insert a newline or style the button differently on a new row.

I am not on an PC with IDE, but something like this should point you in the right direction:

```
        {releasedTime.map((value, index) => {  
          if (index > 5) return <ButtonOnNewLine>...</ButtonOnNewLine>
          return (
            <Button>...</Button>
          );
        })}
```

You can also do the styling of the button related to the index with a modulo.

Or do it like in this codepen with pure css:
https://codepen.io/SakerONE/pen/bdbLNz

Do you get the concept?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it looks like `index` is the point. But in my case if `index` is 20, there would be 15 `<Button />` in the same row also if `index` is 10. In the same `{}` they were rendered under the same `<Body />` How it can be rendered in next row ?  And how to style the related ? I just try to remove `flex` or `alignSelf` but not what i want. Sorry a lots of question.

Comment: you can also do a automatic css break like in this codepen:
https://codepen.io/SakerONE/pen/bdbLNz

Comment: If put two `<div />` they are not stretch the width. In my case i hope <Button /> can  be stretch.  I find my <Button /> style `flex: 1` and `alignSelf: 'stretch',` have existed. I try to adjust my <Body /> styles, add the justifyContent: 'space-around' or 'space-between' or 'center' they are no working.  I want it can like this https://github.com/jskuby/react-native-gridview

Comment: I still try a operator  1index / 5`, i update it in my question. Its still no working :(

Comment: Maybe try this https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/ set the button to 20% and turn flex wrap on. I am on mobile for a few more days, so i can not try :/

Comment: I try to fix the style like `    width: '30%',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',` in `<Button />` . Although it can't stretch only one or two <Button /> but i can accept that at least. Can you post it to an answer ? I will take the answer. Thank you very much !